# EF7.Beta5: Hirachical navigation on answered instances returns null - direct access works

Tags: entity-framework-core

Tested a simple hierarchy of two classes:

```
public class Company
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        ...
        public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    }
```

having added two instances of

```
  public class Department
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        ...
        public Company Company { get; set; }
    }
```

Access `myContext.Company` in a `foreach` loop works.
Access `myContext.Departments` in a `foreach` loop works.
after just created the db entries - even the hierachical navigation works.

BUT 
trying to access (after program restart) a loaded `Company.Departments`  - `Departments` is `null`.

Is my expectation wrong - to get all the former added `Departments` back by direct navigation in any case?
OR
is that an "to be fixed feature"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy loading isn't implemented yet in EF7. If the related entities are already loaded, the navigation properties will be fixed-up. If they're not, the navigation properties will be null unless you load them. Either eagerly...

```cs
var companies = db.Companies.Include(c => c.Departments);
```

...or explicitly.

```cs
db.Departements.Where(d => d.CompanyId == company.Id).Load();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to wait for the full implementation, but could work further.